# autocapitalize="words" broken on mobile Safari in iOS 8,9 - Is there a workaround?

Tags: ios8, mobile-safari, ios13

The `<input>` attribute `autocapitalize="words"` is broken in mobile Safari under iOS 8,9 with the default iOS keyboard.  It uppercases the first 2 letters of the field, not the first letter of each word.

Official documentation says is supported: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html

To test, open the following field on iOS emulator or real device:

```
First name: <input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="words" value="First Name">
```

You can use https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit to test, or this snippet on iOS 8 or 9:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test autocapitalize</title>
   </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="words">autocapitalize="words"</label>
      <input type="text" autocapitalize="words" name="text1" id="words" /><br />
      <label for="sentences">autocapitalize="sentences"</label>
      <input type="text" autocapitalize="sentences" name="text2" id="sentences" /><br />
      <label for="none">autocapitalize="none"</label>
      <input type="text" autocapitalize="none" name="text3" id="none" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm amazed this has been present since 8.x and has passed under the radar.

Is there a known workaround?

Update 10/13:
iPhone 6s+ Safari completely ignores any HTML attribute set on the input field.

Comment: Have you reported this to Apple?

Comment: Also, I don't see the problem in the w3... url you reference -- could this instead be a problem with JavaScript you are using?

Comment: Yes I posted the questions here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/57845#57845

Not sure if that's the best place or there might be somewhere else.

To clarify on the w3 link that I provided you need to replace the HTML markup with

`First name: <input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="words" value="First Name">`

Then you should be able to see the issue

Comment: I'm not sure the forums are the best place -- I would submit something via the Apple Bug Reporter. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Bug 22937164  was filed on Apple's bug reporter. Thanks for the reference Ken.

Comment: I'm really surprised this isn't a bigger issue but perhaps not a lot of folks are using the "words" option...

Comment: This still isn't fixed as of May 2016. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: From iOS 8 still having this issue in iOS 10. What a heck!

Comment: STill not fixed! SHame on you APple!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a workaround for this issue if you are willing to (temporarily) include this library: https://github.com/agrublev/autocapitalize. It does however require jQuery, so might not be ideal on a mobile device. I've created this small piece of code which does the same thing **just for words** without the use of jQuery. It can ofcourse be extented to also include other cases.

The example below also capitalizes the words initially on page ready, instead of just on the 'keyup' event. I've tested the code on several devices and haven't gotten an error. But feel free to comment if something doesn't work or you feel something can be done better.

Note that the 'domReady' function I added works for IE9 and up. Please see [this](http://beeker.io/jquery-document-ready-equivalent-vanilla-javascript) if you require support for an older version.

```
// Create one global variable
var lib = {};

(function ( lib ) {

  lib.autocapitalize_element = function (element) {
    var val = element.value.toLowerCase();
    var split_identifier = " ";
    var split = val.split(split_identifier);
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i ++) {
      var v = split[i];
      if ( v.length ) {
          split[i] = v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.substring(1);
      }
    };
    val = split.join(split_identifier);
    element.value = val;
  }

  lib.autocapitalize_helper = function(element) {
    element.onkeyup = function(e) {
      var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      if (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp)) {
        lib.autocapitalize_element(element);
      }
    };
  }

  lib.autocapitalize = function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[autocapitalize], textarea[autocapitalize]");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      lib.autocapitalize_helper(elements[i]);
      lib.autocapitalize_element(elements[i]);
    }
  }

  lib.domReady = function(callback) {
    document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete" ? callback() : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
  };
}( lib ));


// This function gets called when the dom is ready. I've added it to the lib variable now because I dislike adding global variables, but you can put it anywhere you like.
lib.domReady(function() {
  lib.autocapitalize();
});
```

Comment: Sure. Do you prefer without jQuery? Then I will see what I can whip up tonight ;)